# MS Access SQL, How to return only the newest row before a given date joined to a master table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in a MS Access database as shown below. CustomerId is a primary key and fkCustomerId is a foreign key linked to the CustomerId in the other table.

Customer table

| CustomerId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | David |

Purchase table

| fkCustomerId | OrderDate | fkStockId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2010 | 100 |
| 3 | 08/07/2010 | 101 |
| 2 | 14/01/2011 | 102 |
| 2 | 21/10/2011 | 103 |
| 3 | 02/03/2012 | 104 |
| 1 | 30/09/2012 | 105 |
| 3 | 01/01/2013 | 106 |
| 1 | 18/04/2014 | 107 |
| 3 | 22/11/2015 | 108 |

I am trying to return a list of customers showing the last fkStockId for each customer ordered before a given date.

So for the date 01/10/2012, I'd be looking for a return of

| fkCustomerId | Name | fkStockId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 105 |
| 2 | Bob | 103 |
| 3 | David | 104 |

A solution seems to be escaping me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested select to get last order date.

```
SELECT Purchase.fkCustomerId,
       Name,
       fkStockId
FROM Purchase
JOIN 
(
     SELECT fkCustomerId,
            MAX(OrderDate) as last_OrderDate
     FROM Purchase
     WHERE OrderDate < '01/10/2012'
     GROUP BY fkCustomerId
) AS lastOrder
     ON  lastOrder.fkCustomerId = Purchase.fkCustomerId
     AND last_OrderDate = OrderDate 
LEFT JOIN Customer
     ON Customer.CustomerId = Purchase.fkCustomerId
```

This example assumes `OrderDate` before '01/10/2012'. You might need to change it if you want it to be filtered by a different value.

Another assumption is that there's only one corresponding `fkStockId` for each `OrderDate`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this won't work for a MS Access database as the Partition By clause is not allowed

Comment: Added an alternative solution with nested join